# grails is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: grails

Hi i installed grails at

> c:/grails

directory on my windows 7

after that i created  GRAILS_HOME environment variable as mentioned on grails website

but now when i run this command

> grails integrate-with --intellij

on command prompt it throws an error :

> grails is not recognized as an internal or external command

any thoughts what i am doing wrong here

Comment: Did you put `%GRAILS_HOME%\bin` in your `PATH` ? Just FYI - You don't need to do that to use Grails with Intellij.

Comment: Possibly after setting `GRAILS_HOME`, `cmd` prompt was not restarted. First, verify `grails -version` successfully.

Comment: @dmahapatro it's total path to add. GRAILS_HOME=c:\grails and in path add %GRAILS_HOME%\bin as James Kleeh said

Comment: :) @Mr.Cat Correct. Behaving as a layman, some one would get confused if we do not mention `PATH`.

Comment: %GRAILS_HOME%\bin is in my path

Comment: I restarted my command prompt

Comment: @JamesKleeh this is my PATH variable value looks like: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Apache Group\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\cvsnt%GRAILS_HOME%\bin

Comment: @harshallonare Missing `;` before `%GRAILS_HOME%\bin;`. Add `;` after `bin` as well not to repeat the mistake. :)

Comment: Where is ; after C:\Program Files (x86)\cvsnt?

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro worked like charm

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and did as follows to get rid off.
 Although you have already mentioned that, you set Environment variables. I am assuring again:

```
In environment variables dialogue: (user variables section)
1. Set GRAILS_HOME to your extracted grails version as GRAILS_HOME=D:\GrailsEnvironment\grails-2.1.1
2.  Set JAVA_HOME to your installed jdk version as JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04

In environment variables dialogue: (System variables section)
1. Edit path and add D:\GrailsEnvironment\grails-2.1.1\bin
2.  Edit path and add C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin

If needed reboot your pc again. and in command prompt run 'grails -version' and 'java -version' command to check whether grails and java were perfectly installed.

If error shows then may be your grails package is corrupted, Extract your grails package newly in the specified path again. run the command to check. if necessary reboot and run command.

Thanks
```